# "nvm use 16.13.0" will return this error "exit status 145: The directory is not empty."

Tags: node.js, gulp, nvm

I have 2 versions of node.js , as follow:-

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 17.1.0 (x64) and npm.

C:\Windows\System32>nvm list

    16.13.0
    8.16.2
```

but when i try to use the first version i got this error:-

```
C:\Windows\System32>nvm use 8.16.2
node v8.16.2 (64-bit) is not installed.
```

and when i try to use the second version i got this:-

```
C:\Windows\System32>nvm use 16.13.0
exit status 145: The directory is not empty.
```

so what is going on? thanks

Answer (score 107):

if it is a Windows machine go to C:\Program Files\nodejs.
Then rename that folder to C:\Program Files\nodejsx.
After that please check "nvm use v.v.v."

Comment: Thank you so much It worked for me, I was scuffing for the versions of node.js from all 2days but not gonna any conclusion at EOD. bcz from the starting I was working on Linux, for the first time I had to work with windows os. It Helped me a loot a small thing changed my Hard Work to smart worked, Thank you so much once again.

Comment: how is it working?
And can you tell why am I requiring usage of admin cmd instead of running cmd normally

Comment: why does this work...

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 28):

I just fixed it by uninstalling Node.js from the Settings -> Apps menu.
According to the https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/pull/615 pull request, nvm cannot change the version because it's conflicting with the normally installed Node.js version. Try deleting Node.js from the Apps settings menu.

Comment: Worked, but it is quite strange, as I used to "nvm use" even with node.js installed.

Comment: In my case the problem was that I was switching the node version whilst I had an open terminal running ng serve. Closing the process solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 15):

When this happen:

```
C:\Windows\System32>nvm use 16.13.0
exit status 145: The directory is not empty.
```

Just make sure, the nodejs folder is empty, check `C:\Program Files\nodejs` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs`, otherwise delete the content. Then try again `nvm use XXXX`  (xxxx is the version)

Answer (score 2):

On windows 10, It fixed after I uninstalled my node.js application from control panel. And install specific version with `nvm install x.x.x` then `nvm use x.x.x` using Powershell in **administration mode**.

Answer (score 1):

I meet same issue. I have resolved as:

Make sure you delete all old nodejs.

step 1:uninstall nodejs and remove node_home and npm_home;

step 2:
download nvm and Install it. My OS is win, so link is :
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases.
if your OS is MAC or Linux, you can use `brew` or `apt install` utils to install.

step3:
open cmd.exe, run it as "administrator", checking NVM_HOME and NVM_SYMLINK
example:

```
NVM_HOME=D:\dev\node\nvm
NVM_SYMLINK=D:\dev\node\nodejs
```

Note:**make sure nvm home and nvm symlink need in diff forlder**.

if not set , your must set manual and add path:

```
%NVM_HOME%
%NVM_SYMLINK%
```

open a new cmd.exe terminal, and make sure these is OK.

step 4:
Open new terminal prompt:

```
run 'nvm on'
run 'nvm list'
run 'nvm install 14'
run 'nvm use 14.18.2'
run 'node --version'
```

[image]
enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

suggest you uninstall local nodejs from control panel and try again nvm use *******

Comment: This is not an answer.  Consider givin feedbacks using comments not New answer.   This way we keep answers reliable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that nvm cannot update the "junction" folder (symlink), which is in your case pointing to "program files", if executed from a non-admin prompt (case 1). Or the junction folder was overwritten by "real" nodejs, and cannot be used as such anymore, which probably means that you installed nodejs *after* nvm (case 2). The junction folder is defined by the NVM_SYMLINK environment variable.

Please note that this was improved a bit in the later releases of NVM, now the messages should be cleaner, and also NVM should be now smart enough to *rise an admin elevation prompt automatically* if it is necessary to update the junction folder (i.e. if user's junction is pointing to something inside "program files" but he tries to update it from a non-admin prompt).